# Does data load faster from an object's property or from json?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, design-patterns, coding-style

I am wondering if there's any performance difference at all between initializing a class from json or from an object.

So, imagine the following scenario:

```
func getDataFromServer(){

    ...

    var data = doc.data()
    let obj = Object(id: String, prices: [data["price"] as! Double], .. , .. , .. , .. , ..)

    if (dictionary[id] != nil) {
       // obj already exists. Update its info.

       var oldObj = dictionary[id]
       oldObj.updateInfoWith(price: obj.prices[0], .. , .. , .. , .. , ..) //(1)
       //behind the scenes updateInfoWith does: oldObj.prices.append(obj.prices[0])
    }
    else{
        objects.append(obj)
    }
}
```

At the (1) line, is there any difference in performance from getting the price from `obj.prices[0]` or from `data["price"] as! Double`? The data json tree is as huge as the number of properties of an Object class, such that an Object class gets all data contained in a data json tree. An Object has about 10 properties, being three of them arrays (prices being one of them).

Comment: If you have questions about performance, write a benchmark to compare them using your own data to see which is more performant based on your actual requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the JSON Data content , if your JSON data is really `quite big and contains a lot of Arrays and Dictionaries` its better to use a `Object class` for that , as if you Filter JSON on same Controller where you need to display data will `take memory` i.e `Load on single controller` whereas Object class will divide the load there iterate through JSON and give you specific result in one line

So it depend on the `JSON Structure`

**-> Either you can use Object class for Big Structured JSON so not to overload a single controller for all processing**

**-> Can make use of Small structs that will Carry the Data from JSON so, you do not need to Iterate again and again in JSON for the same Data**

**NOTE:** I prefer object class for your case as you said Data is quite big

Answer (score 0):

Those operations: running a getter vs. accessing a dictionary (and for that matter [`valueForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1412591-value)) are very comparable, if not nearly identical, performance-wise.

Bigger levers on performance are going to come from not fetching as much data, and being lazy about allocations once you have it (for example, just keeping around querySnapshots and only getting the docs or doc.data() when that data is demanded by the UI).